# In profiles reported by aa-status, what do double (//) or triple (///) slashes do?

Tags: apparmor

Apparmor's `aa-status` command reports the status of apparmor, but what do the double and triple slashes mean or do in the list of profiles reported?

For example, what is the double slash (`//`) in `/usr/bin/evince-previewer//sanitized_helper` for?

Here is a typical aa-status output:

```
# aa-status    
apparmor module is loaded.
67 profiles are loaded.
50 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /snap/core/13886/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /snap/core/13886/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /usr/bin/evince
   /usr/bin/evince-previewer
   /usr/bin/evince-previewer//sanitized_helper
   /usr/bin/evince-thumbnailer
   /usr/bin/evince//sanitized_helper
   /usr/bin/freshclam
   /usr/bin/man
   /usr/bin/pidgin
   /usr/bin/pidgin//sanitized_helper
   /usr/bin/totem
   /usr/bin/totem-audio-preview
   /usr/bin/totem-video-thumbnailer
   /usr/bin/totem//sanitized_helper
   /usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine
   /usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine//mount-namespace-capture-helper
   /usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5
   /usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*
   /usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*//pxgsettings
   /usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-*//sanitized_helper
   /usr/lib/telepathy/telepathy-ofono
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session//chromium
   /usr/sbin/cups-browsed
   /usr/sbin/cupsd
   /usr/sbin/cupsd//third_party
   /usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi
   /usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi///usr/sbin/mysqld
   /usr/sbin/ntpd
   apt-cacher-ng
   lsb_release
   man_filter
   man_groff
   nvidia_modprobe
   nvidia_modprobe//kmod
   snap-update-ns.core
   snap-update-ns.snap-store
   snap.core.hook.configure
   snap.snap-store.hook.configure
   snap.snap-store.snap-store
   snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software
   snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software-local-file
   tcpdump
   thunderbird
   thunderbird//browser_java
   thunderbird//browser_openjdk
   thunderbird//gpg
   thunderbird//sanitized_helper
17 profiles are in complain mode.
   /usr/bin/irssi
   /usr/sbin/dnsmasq
   /usr/sbin/dnsmasq//libvirt_leaseshelper
   avahi-daemon
   identd
   klogd
   mdnsd
   nmbd
   nscd
   ping
   smbd
   smbldap-useradd
   smbldap-useradd///etc/init.d/nscd
   syslog-ng
   syslogd
   thunderbird///opt/firefox/firefox-bin
   traceroute
16 processes have profiles defined.
7 processes are in enforce mode.
   /usr/bin/evince (12497) 
   /usr/bin/freshclam (1328) 
   /usr/sbin/cups-browsed (128117) 
   /usr/sbin/cupsd (128098) 
   /usr/sbin/ntpd (1369) 
   /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird-bin (211830) thunderbird
   /usr/lib/thunderbird/thunderbird-bin (211927) thunderbird
9 processes are in complain mode.
   /usr/sbin/dnsmasq (828) 
   /usr/sbin/avahi-daemon (703) avahi-daemon
   /usr/sbin/avahi-daemon (740) avahi-daemon
   /usr/sbin/nmbd (1332) nmbd
   /usr/sbin/nscd (716) nscd
   /usr/sbin/smbd (1531) smbd
   /usr/sbin/smbd (1705) smbd
   /usr/sbin/smbd (1706) smbd
   /usr/sbin/smbd (1708) smbd
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

Comment: @Quasímodo, no, we're talking of apparmor profiles here, not file paths. Here it's more like the profile of an evince process that has transitioned to a `sanitized_helper` subprofile after having executed a helper application. See the "Directed profile transitions" in `apparmor.d(5)`

Comment: See https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.0/security/apparmor/policy.c#L35